# How can I post more than one value from an input field when serializing a form and sending with ajax?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

I have a form that has some radio buttons (this is a dynamic form, with different radio buttons depending on the page, the entire form is a step selector). At first the radio buttons only needed to contain one value, but this has changed.

Example input:

```
<input type="radio" id="PRO ontwerpcontrole" name="Ontwerp" value="7.44">
```

When serializing my form like this:

```
$("body").on("click","#orderbtn",function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var $producten = $("#formsid form").serialize();
    var $order = 'yes';
    $.ajax({
     type:'post',
     url:"catalog/calcdiv.php",
     data:{
         form_data: $producten,
         order: $order
     },
     success:function(data){
         var obj = JSON.parse(data);

         if(obj[1].status == 'error'){
         }else if(obj[1].status == 'success'){
             var message = obj[1].message;

             $.ajax({
                 type:'post',
                 url:"includes/winkelmandpopup.php",
                 data:{
                     producten: $producten
                 },
                 success:function(data1){
                     $( "#orderresult" ).show().empty().append(data1);
                     $('#orderresult').modal();
                     refreshcount(true);
                 }
             });
         }
     }
 });
});
```

I get a string that I can use, like: `Ontwerp=7.44&etcetcetc`. But now I need more than just the 7.44, so I tried adding a `data-*` attribute hoping that the serialize function would pick the data from there automatically, unfortunately this did not work.

I also tried just adding a custom attribute like this:

```
<input type="radio" id="PRO ontwerpcontrole" bleed="10mm" name="Ontwerp" value="7.44">
```

But this does not get added to the serialized form string.

Adding hidden inputs also did not work, because when serializing, all hidden inputs get posted while I only want the data from the selected radio button.

What can I do?

Adding something to the value and exploding the data with PHP is not an option unfortunately.

Comment: Did you try getting that data-attribute value and attaching as new parameter to your serialize string using `$("#formsid form").serialize()+"&yourvariablename="+thatvalue` ?

Comment: @Swati No I didn't try that, but the step form is dynamic which means there is not one single version. There are multiple pages that each have different options (radio inputs) inside the step form. So adding a paramater like that won't work.

Comment: @Swati Also one step can have multiple choices with the same name, for example: `<input type="radio" id="PRO ontwerpcontrole" name="Ontwerp" data-bleed="10mm" value="7.44">` and `<input type="radio" id="PRO ontwerpcontrole" name="Ontwerp" data-bleed="20mm" value="7.44">`

Comment: Then check which radio button are checked inside your event handler and get that value only .

Comment: @Swati Thank! Got it working with your method.